# How to verify a password against a database on a remote server?

Tags: security, passwords, django-rest-framework

We are building an api that helps third party apps verify UID/password combinations against a database on a remote server.

When a user enters his username and password in the third party app and hits submit, the username and password have to be sent over to our api securely, we take the UID and password, send it over to a remote server that compares it against the database and tells us if the combination is valid or not. How do we send the password? How do we hash it so that it can be un-hashed and verified by the remote server that has the database?

We are using the django rest framework.

Comment: Unhash? Like, calculate the SHA-1 hash of 1GB video and get the original video back from the 160-bit string? You probably mean **encrypt** and there's an existing widespread technology for that: HTTPS. Said that, it's unclear if you want to make it work with a specific service or you want a general purpose solution. In the first case, there's probably no need to transmit the original password at all.

Comment: The third party app may vary but the server that has the database stays the same. The varying third party app makes a request to us and we make a request to the database.

Answer (score 1):

First you want to use a strong SSL connection.

Second you can use a salt like "mysecretsalt$"§%§$%§$" and hash it like

$var = sha1($salt.$pass);

Then send $var as authtoken.

On the remote Server you save all salted password on your database and compare that with the token or just salt it when ever it is requested and compare the salted password from the database with the sent token...

Comment: The recommended hashes to store passwords are Bcrypt or Blowfish, as implemented by [password_hash()](http://php.net/password_hash). Said that, any hash we choose is useless if it doesn't match the target database and we don't have any clue about that.

Comment: But how do I compare a hashed password(sent by us) with an unhashed, salted password(generated on the remote on request)? Is the result of a sha1 hashing the same irrespective of server?

Comment: Exactly Álvaro, how do we bring the two passwords to the same 'format' to compare?

Comment: on the targetserver use:

Comment: $salteddbpass= sha1($salt.$dbpass);

if ($requestedtoken == $salteddbpass) {...

The salt must be the same on both machines. I would say even md5 as hashing function would be good enough. Since when someone cracks your SSL you got some other serious problems. People who do that might as well come and put a gun in your face to get the users password...

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use SSL for all network communication, there's no need to "pre-hash" it. Just send it along.

Anything else you do (encryption, etc) is just going to poorly re-invent SSL anyway, so just do it.